# SVG path transition works different in Firefox

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition

I am trying to generate path transition in d3 svg by using stroke-dasharray,stroke-dashoffset attributes. My need is to draw the path line slowly for particular duration. For this , i am setting stroke-dasharray as the total length of the path and animating the stroke-dashoffset attributes in path element. My code for this will be looking like

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
          .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
          .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); }); 

var path = svg.append("path")//No I18N
            .datum(serData)
            .attr("d", line)
            .attr("class", "line")//No I18N
            .style('stroke', 'blue')
            .style('stroke-width', 2)


            var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

            path
              .style("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
              .style("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
              .transition()
              .duration(2000)
              .ease("linear")
              .style("stroke-dashoffset", 0)
```

**source** for **My expected transition result** looks alike :http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326

**Problem faced**: The above code ***works properly in chrome*** as i expected. But in firefox, Animation starts from full line path and erases the full path and drawn it again. i.e ***animation taking twic**e*. If i change the value for "stoke-dashoffset" to *(totalLength/2)*,its working properly in firefox, but not in chrome(here transition starts from middle of the path)

WHat is wrong here??any help??

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox you need to divide the length of the path by the stroke-width:

```
var offset = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? totalLength / path.node().strokeWidth : totalLength;
path.style("stroke-dashoffset", offset);
```